# Is it possible to get $\phi \in S_{16}$ if the order of $\phi$ is 56?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I had an exam of Abstract Algebra today, and one of the questions was: Is it possible to get $\phi \in S_{16}$ if the order of $\phi$ is $56$? If so, give an exam, if not prove it.

$S_{16}$ is simply the permutation group of $16$ elements.

Does someone could enlighten me on this? I did not find answers to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: if $\sigma, \tau\in S_{16}$ are disjoint cycles, what is the order of $\sigma\tau$ in terms of the orders of $\sigma$ and $\tau$?

Comment: So the answer at this question is no, right?

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: I have needed more informations please. An example maybe?

Comment: Take $S_5$ as an example. What is the order of $(1\ 2)$? What is the order of $(3\ 4\ 5)$? And, what is the order of $(1\ 2)(3\ 4\ 5)$? Can you generalize that to your question? (I'm not going to just give you the answer to your question...)